# Facebook API Graph - posting a status update to a Facebook Page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am following the Facebook developer documentation for making a post to a Facebook 'Page' as the Page itself, which according to the docs requires impersonation. I've gotten the access token for the page itself, as well as the Page's ID, by making a call to the "accounts" feed for the user who's the admin for the Page. I then POST to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[Page_ID]/feed
```

With the post items

```
access_token
```

and

```
message
```

containing the access token and the message, and I get a JSON string back with a post ID. Which all seems to indicate that it is posting the message to the page. HOWEVER, when I go to the particular Page, it doesn't display the posted status.

Does anyone perhaps have any idea why that might be?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make sure to get the "publish_stream" permission from the user?

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions